# Can anyone explain what are the apron taxiway and aircraft holding taxiway with an illustration, please?

Tags: airport-design, taxiways

Note: There are 3 types of taxiway

1) Apron taxiway

2) Aircraft holding taxiway

3) Rapid exit taxiway

Comment: I have never heard of "apron taxiway" or "aircraft holding taxiway". Where did you get these terms from?

Comment: This question is perfectly clear. Please don't vote to close just because you don't know the answer!

Comment: @Bianfable I am a cadet air traffic controller and I got this information from my airport design and management course.

Comment: @J.Hougaard and thanks for your support. I am sorry to see my question was closed; it can be beneficial for aviation lovers :)

Comment: An apron is what you wear when you bake cookies to keep the flour off your dress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apron taxiways are just taxiways, except they are on the apron. They help planes on the apron connect to the main taxiways or the planes on the main taxiways connect to the apron.

I don't know what you meant by holding taxiways, but I assume you meant runway threshold or runway holding point. In that case, here's your illustration:

[image: Medium commercial sized airport]

Notice how the apron taxiways are only on the apron and how they lead to the main taxiways! Also, the blue circled areas are runway holding points.

Legend:
Yellow lines: Apron Taxiways;
Red line: Runway;
Blue circles: Runway holding points;
Orange lines: Main taxiways and high speed taxiway;

Oh, and the high speed taxiway I just mentioned is the slanted taxiway connecting the rwy and taxiway without a holding point. That would answer your Rapid Exit Taxiway question.

Yes your terms are clear, but they are not the exact terms that we use in aviation. I guess that was why that guy said your terms weren't clear. But, I do understand them. It's just you wouldn't use them if you were an actual pilot.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed illustration and expression; it was clear. And for your assumption about holding taxiway I know this used for an apron, and refer the plane's taxi from apron to apron taxiway maybe; I do not know clearly; and you understand me correctly, thanks for that. That guy didn't know what I meant; because these are detailed information; and in aviation nobody know all info. I am cadet air traffic controller and I got this information from my airport design and management course.

Comment: Cool that you're in air cadets! And you're welcome. I mean that guy, he I guess he was just confused. But I think we should forgive him.